# AS3/Flash: XML node deletion based on two values

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, nodes

I have that code for the deletion of a especific node:

```
var db: XML = <db>
    <entry>
        <Name>JAMES</Name>
        <Surname>MAILER</Surname>
        <Date>28/08/2013</Date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <Name>NATA</Name>
        <Surname>KING</Surname>
        <Date>28/08/2013</Date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <Name>ROMAN</Name>
        <Surname>ALDA</Surname>
        <Date>28/08/2013</Date>
    </entry>
    <entry>...</entry>
</db>

clean();

function clean():void
{
var tempXML:XML = <db></db>;
var count:int = db.children().length();
trace (count);

for (i=0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (db.children()[i].Name == "JAMES" && db.children()[i].Surname == "MAILER")
    {
                    //do nothing
    }else{
        tempXML.appendChild(db.children()[i]);
    }
}
db = tempXML;
}
```

As you can see I'm using the else to add the nodes that doesn't match with the conditional statement.

If I use:

```
if (db.children()[i].Name == "JAMES" && db.children()[i].Surname == "MAILER")
```

I can avoid the "else" but the code removes all the nodes that have JAMES or MEX as values.

The "do nothing" script do the job, but it's ugly.

Is there a better way using loops and simple comparition?

Thanks,

and cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use "!" to invert (NOT) the Boolean value of the condition:

```
if (!(db.children()[i].Name == "JAMES" && db.children()[i].Surname == "MAILER"))
{
    tempXML.appendChild(db.children()[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks djib! I did use another method, but yours works as well as. Both are nice solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use E4X syntax for this, example:

```
..
const lookupXMLList : XMLList = db.*.(Name != "JAMES" && Surname != "MAILER");
trace("Result:", lookupXMLList.toXMLString());
..
```

But, in your case, the best solution is - removing useless nodes:

```
..
const removingXMLList : XMLList = db.*.(Name == "JAMES" && Surname == "MAILER");
for(var i : String in removingXMLList.*) delete removingXMLList[0];
trace("Result:", removingXMLList.toXMLString());
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Before the loop:

```
var test2:XML = dbase.copy();
```

Inside the loop:

```
if (test2.employee[i].Name == "JAMES" && test2.employee[i].Surname == "MAILER")
{
   delete test2.employee[i];
}
```

I did use this one.

Thanks dimpiax and djib.